# How to redefine OpenCV's Mat type

Tags: opencv, g++

Using `g++`, I tried to redefine the `Opencv's Mat` type as

```
#define      CV_32FC1       CV_TYPE_1
```

But I have error as `invalid arguments` at

```
Mat LO_Coefs;
LO_Coefs.create(1, cnt, CV_TYPE_1);
```

Comment: `#define    CV_TYPE_1    CV_32FC1`  (imho, you got it the wrongway around)

Comment: Y thanks, confused :)